# WP_Query() doesn't work inside a custom class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

What would prevent `WP_Query()` from working inside a class method?

```
class MyClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->myFunc();
    }
    public function myFunc()
    {
        global $post, $wp_query;
        $args_ = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'suppress_filters' => false
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args_ ); // doesn't work
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

It all works perfectly outside of the class, I can't find a logical reason as to why it does not work inside.

Update:
The displayed error is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in
>   /home/oricoil/public_html/roofdagan1/wp-includes/query.php on line
>   3174

Comment: try by decalaring $wpdb as well in your global variables

 global $wpdb, $post, $wp_query;

Comment: @yamu I declared $wpdb, not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be a conflict with some other variable, declared inside your class?

### EDIT

The solution (see the comments) was changing

```
$this->myFunc();
```

to

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'myFunc'));
```

Comment: if your class has `private $post;` or `$post = something` it would be a problem.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/oricoil/public_html/roofdagan1/wp-includes/query.php on line 3174

Comment: An advice: you should add that to your question, the message make things really clearer :) Seeing the error I guess you're using your class outside wordpress environment... You should include wp-load.php on the top of the class file in order to use wordpress functions.

Comment: I think this link should help you: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is_user_logged_in A fast thought is adding `do_action('init');` to your `__contruct()` function, **before** calling `myFunc`.

Comment: I added `do_action('init');` before calling `myFunc`.
Now I got error: 
**Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on a non-object in /home/oricoil/public_html/roofdagan1/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 113**

Comment: I've searched in the wordpress codes and `do_action('init')` should be called just by including `wp-load.php`, you can remove it from your code, sorry. Can you paste the part of the code that you are including *wp-load.php* and the part that you're creating your *MyClass* instance?

Comment: So this is a plugin?! If so I think you just have to change `$this->setAll();` to `add_action('init', array($this, 'setAll'));`. Don't forget to erase the do_action I told you wrongly to add.

Comment: Thank you, you are special in wordpress, the error gone, sorry for that I didn't considered important to clarify that it is plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problems. My solution is add a back slash and it works now.

```
$professor = new \WP_Query(array(
           'post_type'=>'professor',
            's'=>sanitize_text_field($data['term'])
        ));
```

Comment: I just tested it again.  you can add.    use WP_Query; at the begining of the class file.

Comment: This solution is worked for me. I was too confused and tried lots of way to use Wp_Query() inside custom plugin. But every time I got Wp_Query() class error. Now it is resolved by adding simple "\"  just before Wp_Query().
Thank you Gordon Xie